# Poi Formula evaluation

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am facing difficulties while reading formula cell values with POI

I have created formula cell as follows:

```
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA); 
cell.setCellFormula("SUM(D8..F8)");
```

And I am reading it as follow:

```
double formulaCellValue = row.getCell((short) 7).getNumericCellValue();
```

When read this way(using `getNumericCellValue()`), I am always getting the value of 0.0.

Any quick help in this regard would be highly appriciated.

Comment: What do you do after you setCellForumla? Do you set any of the values in D8..F8?

Answer (score 8):

After you're done setting all your formulas, you need to trigger a recalculation. See the [why evaluate docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#WhyEvaluate) for the background on why you need to do it, and the [Evaluation docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) for details. Quick answer is you'd likely want to do something like:

```
HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);
```

Don't call it until you're done adding / editing all your cells though! You can also trigger the evaluation of just one cell, see the [docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) for details of the various options if you need full control.