# Why the data write by poi in excel file was missing after I write this file again?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I write a method "writeData" to write a column data from an existing excel file into a new excel file by apache poi. It works well. But when I try to call this method again, the previous data was missing. Why? Does anybody can help me?

```
public class ReadData {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    Workbook wb, wb1;
    Sheet sheet, sheet1;
    Row row;
    Row row1;   
    static int cell;
    Cell cell1;


    static ArrayList<Cell> list1 = new ArrayList<Cell>();
    static ArrayList<Cell> list2 = new ArrayList<Cell>();



    public static ArrayList<Cell> readData(String filename, int cellNum, ArrayList array){

    try{        

        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(filename);
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);



        for (int j=sheet.getLastRowNum(); j>0; j--) {

            Row row = sheet.getRow(j);
            Cell cell = row.getCell(cellNum);


            array.add(cell);



            System.out.println(cell);

        }


    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Wrong!" + e.getMessage());
        e.getStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    return array;
    }


    public static void writeData(int cellNo, ArrayList<Cell> array){


        Workbook wb1 = new HSSFWorkbook();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

            try{
                fos = new FileOutputStream("3.xls");
                Sheet sheet1 = wb1.createSheet("Data");



                for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
                Row row1 = sheet1.createRow(i);
                Cell cell1 = row1.createCell(cellNo);
                cell1.setCellValue(array.get(i).getNumericCellValue());
                }

                wb1.write(fos);
                fos.close();

                }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

    readData("1.xls",0,list1);  
    writeData(0,list1);
    readData("2.xls",0,list2);  
    writeData(1,list2);
}

}
```

Comment: You're always overwriting the previous file: you're using a fixed filename, and re-creating a new file each time you run `writeData()`

Comment: So do you know how to fix it?

Comment: That would depend on exactly what the expected behavior is. Seems like you should make all your calls to readData(), building up your data set, then finally write it out in a single Excel file.  I've never used POI, so can't comment beyond that.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good idea. I'll try it later.What I want to do is to copy two columns from two existing excel file respectively. I'm trying to create a file first and then call a method to modify that file. Hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you start your workbook from scratch and the `FileOuputStream` overwrites your file.

You need to open your workbook linking it to your file. For that, construct your Excel with and InputStream.

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("3.xls");
wb1 = new HSSFWorkbook(input);
```

For writing, I am not exactly sure if you really need to use a `FileOuputStream`, maybe closing the workbook properly will be enough (works with XSSFWorkbooks).

The OutputStream will work but you may have some error if the Input is equal to the Output.

Comment: Thanks for your helps. I have another question. Do you know how to implement the excel functions which is not included in the poi evaluation list, such as slope? "SLOPE" is a regular function in excel but I cannot evaluate it by poi.

Comment: There are specific tools to evaluate formulas (Only pn HSSFWorkbook for the moment). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747034/poi-formula-evaluation?answertab=votes#tab-top) If there is not in the list, the only way is to evaluate it yourself... Good luck for that.